# command not found make[2]: *** [Makefile:422: xnee.info] Error 127

Tags: software-installation, compiling

i have tried to install the [xnee](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/xnee/) for auto macro recording by this instruction:

```
#Check out xnee
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@cvs.savannah.gnu.org:/sources/xnee co xnee

#Enter the Xnee directory
cd xnee

#Generate the makefiles and build

make -f Makefile.cvs
./configure 
make
make install
```

but get this result (more complete information [here](https://pastebin.com/XnycxwMt)):

```
so@sosa:~/Downloads/xnee-3.19$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -I../include -I../../libxnee/include      -g -DUSE_VERBOSE -DNO_BUF_VERBOSE     -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT   -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT  -g -O2 -MT parse.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/parse.Tpo -c -o parse.o parse.c
parse.c: In function 'xnee_parse_cnee_option':
parse.c:623:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cnee_record_replay'; did you mean 'xnee_is_force_replay'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  623 |       cnee_record_replay(xd);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |       xnee_is_force_replay
mv -f .deps/parse.Tpo .deps/parse.Po
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -I../include -I../../libxnee/include      -g -DUSE_VERBOSE -DNO_BUF_VERBOSE     -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT   -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT  -g -O2   -static   -o cnee cnee_fake.o cnee_printer.o cnee_strings.o cnee_demo.o main.o parse.o -L../../libxnee/src -lxnee  -lX11 -lXtst -lXi -ldl  
libtool: link: gcc -I../include -I../../libxnee/include -g -DUSE_VERBOSE -DNO_BUF_VERBOSE -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT -g -O2 -o cnee cnee_fake.o cnee_printer.o cnee_strings.o cnee_demo.o main.o parse.o  -L../../libxnee/src /home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/libxnee/src/.libs/libxnee.a -lX11 -lXtst -lXi -ldl
Generating texi file from: cnee
./cnee --texipage > cnee.texi
make  all-am
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/cnee/src'
./cnee --manpage > cnee.1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/cnee/src'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/cnee/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/cnee'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/cnee'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/cnee'
Making all in gnee
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/gnee'
Making all in src
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/gnee/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -I"../../libxnee"/include -I../../     -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT  -g -O2 -MT gnee-main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gnee-main.Tpo -c -o gnee-main.o `test -f 'main.c' || echo './'`main.c
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkobject.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcontainer.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkbin.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from main.c:35:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktypeutils.h:236:1: warning: 'GTypeDebugFlags' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  236 | void            gtk_type_init   (GTypeDebugFlags    debug_flags);
      | ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from main.c:35:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:679:1: note: declared here
  679 | {
      | ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolitem.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkmenutoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:126,
                 from main.c:35:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktooltips.h:73:3: warning: 'GTimeVal' is deprecated: Use 'GDateTime' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   73 |   GTimeVal last_popdown;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from main.c:35:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:547:8: note: declared here
  547 | struct _GTimeVal
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
mv -f .deps/gnee-main.Tpo .deps/gnee-main.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -I"../../libxnee"/include -I../../     -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT  -g -O2 -MT gnee-support.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gnee-support.Tpo -c -o gnee-support.o `test -f 'support.c' || echo './'`support.c
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkobject.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcontainer.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkbin.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from support.c:15:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktypeutils.h:236:1: warning: 'GTypeDebugFlags' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  236 | void            gtk_type_init   (GTypeDebugFlags    debug_flags);
      | ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from support.c:15:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:679:1: note: declared here
  679 | {
      | ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolitem.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkmenutoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:126,
                 from support.c:15:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktooltips.h:73:3: warning: 'GTimeVal' is deprecated: Use 'GDateTime' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   73 |   GTimeVal last_popdown;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from support.c:15:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:547:8: note: declared here
  547 | struct _GTimeVal
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
mv -f .deps/gnee-support.Tpo .deps/gnee-support.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -I"../../libxnee"/include -I../../     -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT  -g -O2 -MT gnee-interface.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gnee-interface.Tpo -c -o gnee-interface.o `test -f 'interface.c' || echo './'`interface.c
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkobject.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcontainer.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkbin.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from interface.c:16:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktypeutils.h:236:1: warning: 'GTypeDebugFlags' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  236 | void            gtk_type_init   (GTypeDebugFlags    debug_flags);
      | ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from interface.c:16:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:679:1: note: declared here
  679 | {
      | ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolitem.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkmenutoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:126,
                 from interface.c:16:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktooltips.h:73:3: warning: 'GTimeVal' is deprecated: Use 'GDateTime' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   73 |   GTimeVal last_popdown;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from interface.c:16:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:547:8: note: declared here
  547 | struct _GTimeVal
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
interface.c: In function 'create_gnee_window':
interface.c:247:7: warning: 'gdk_pixbuf_unref' is deprecated: Use 'g_object_unref' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  247 |       gdk_pixbuf_unref (gnee_window_icon_pixbuf);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkpixbuf.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcairo.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from interface.c:16:
/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-core.h:232:12: note: declared here
  232 | void       gdk_pixbuf_unref    (GdkPixbuf *pixbuf);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mv -f .deps/gnee-interface.Tpo .deps/gnee-interface.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -I"../../libxnee"/include -I../../     -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT  -g -O2 -MT gnee-callbacks.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gnee-callbacks.Tpo -c -o gnee-callbacks.o `test -f 'callbacks.c' || echo './'`callbacks.c
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkobject.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcontainer.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkbin.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from callbacks.c:30:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktypeutils.h:236:1: warning: 'GTypeDebugFlags' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  236 | void            gtk_type_init   (GTypeDebugFlags    debug_flags);
      | ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from callbacks.c:30:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:679:1: note: declared here
  679 | {
      | ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolitem.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkmenutoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:126,
                 from callbacks.c:30:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktooltips.h:73:3: warning: 'GTimeVal' is deprecated: Use 'GDateTime' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   73 |   GTimeVal last_popdown;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from callbacks.c:30:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:547:8: note: declared here
  547 | struct _GTimeVal
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
mv -f .deps/gnee-callbacks.Tpo .deps/gnee-callbacks.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -I"../../libxnee"/include -I../../     -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT  -g -O2 -MT gnee-recordables.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gnee-recordables.Tpo -c -o gnee-recordables.o `test -f 'recordables.c' || echo './'`recordables.c
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkobject.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcontainer.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkbin.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from recordables.h:28,
                 from recordables.c:26:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktypeutils.h:236:1: warning: 'GTypeDebugFlags' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  236 | void            gtk_type_init   (GTypeDebugFlags    debug_flags);
      | ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from recordables.h:28,
                 from recordables.c:26:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:679:1: note: declared here
  679 | {
      | ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolitem.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkmenutoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:126,
                 from recordables.h:28,
                 from recordables.c:26:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktooltips.h:73:3: warning: 'GTimeVal' is deprecated: Use 'GDateTime' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   73 |   GTimeVal last_popdown;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from recordables.h:28,
                 from recordables.c:26:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:547:8: note: declared here
  547 | struct _GTimeVal
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
mv -f .deps/gnee-recordables.Tpo .deps/gnee-recordables.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -I"../../libxnee"/include -I../../     -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT  -g -O2 -MT gnee-gnee_xnee.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gnee-gnee_xnee.Tpo -c -o gnee-gnee_xnee.o `test -f 'gnee_xnee.c' || echo './'`gnee_xnee.c
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkobject.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcontainer.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkbin.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from gnee_xnee.c:26:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktypeutils.h:236:1: warning: 'GTypeDebugFlags' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  236 | void            gtk_type_init   (GTypeDebugFlags    debug_flags);
      | ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from gnee_xnee.c:26:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:679:1: note: declared here
  679 | {
      | ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolitem.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkmenutoolbutton.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:126,
                 from gnee_xnee.c:26:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktooltips.h:73:3: warning: 'GTimeVal' is deprecated: Use 'GDateTime' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   73 |   GTimeVal last_popdown;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from gnee_xnee.c:26:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:547:8: note: declared here
  547 | struct _GTimeVal
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
mv -f .deps/gnee-gnee_xnee.Tpo .deps/gnee-gnee_xnee.Po
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT  -g -O2 -static   -o gnee gnee-main.o gnee-support.o gnee-interface.o gnee-callbacks.o gnee-recordables.o gnee-gnee_xnee.o -L"../../libxnee"/ -L"../../libxnee"/.. -L"../../libxnee"/src -lxnee  -lX11 -lXtst -lXi -ldl -lpthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype  
libtool: link: gcc -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -DXNEE_XINPUT_SUPPORT -g -O2 -o gnee gnee-main.o gnee-support.o gnee-interface.o gnee-callbacks.o gnee-recordables.o gnee-gnee_xnee.o  -L../../libxnee/ -L../../libxnee/.. -L../../libxnee/src /home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/libxnee/src/.libs/libxnee.a -lX11 -lXtst -lXi -ldl -lpthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype -pthread
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/gnee/src'
Making all in man
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/gnee/man'
cat gnee.1.in | sed "s/__VERSION_TAG__/3.20/g" > gnee.1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/gnee/man'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/gnee'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/gnee'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/gnee'
Making all in pnee
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/pnee'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/pnee'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/pnee'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/pnee'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/doc'
restore=: && backupdir=".am$$" && \
am__cwd=`pwd` && CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && \
rm -rf $backupdir && mkdir $backupdir && \
if ( --version) >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
  for f in xnee.info xnee.info-[0-9] xnee.info-[0-9][0-9] xnee.i[0-9] xnee.i[0-9][0-9]; do \
    if test -f $f; then mv $f $backupdir; restore=mv; else :; fi; \
  done; \
else :; fi && \
cd "$am__cwd"; \
if    -I . \
 -o xnee.info xnee.texi; \
then \
  rc=0; \
  CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd .; \
else \
  rc=$?; \
  CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && \
  $restore $backupdir/* `echo "./xnee.info" | sed 's|[^/]*$||'`; \
fi; \
rm -rf $backupdir; exit $rc
/bin/bash: line 9: -I: command not found
make[2]: *** [Makefile:422: xnee.info] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee/doc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:442: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee'
make: *** [Makefile:374: all] Error 2
so@sosa:~/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee$
```

my OS is:

```
so@sosa:~/Downloads/xnee-3.19/t/xnee$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla (development branch)
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

Comment: Judging from all the messages about deprecated functions, it seems that the software is written for an older release of GTK than what you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Your build is failing because you don’t have `makeinfo`, and the build expects to find it:

```
if $(MAKEINFO) $(AM_MAKEINFOFLAGS) $(MAKEINFOFLAGS) -I $(srcdir) \
```

is the line which fails in your case — the build can’t cope with an empty `$(MAKEINFO)`.

A simpler solution on Ubuntu would be to install the package:

```
sudo apt install xnee
```

Comment: SO, does it happen because of main files and i as simple user not developer, can not solve it by myself!?

Comment: If you only want to use Xnee, why not install the package? `apt install xnee`.